# how to use texturepacker json in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

i use texturepacker to export 2dSprite and import to unity3d . I want to know : 1:can i use texturepacker export json on unity3d 2:how to use texturepacker json on my sprite , just like cocos2d-x. 3:have any website , blog or tutorial to learn about it .

Answer (score 0):

It would be easiest if you use some framework for UI, for example NGUI from Unity3d Asset Store. It has ability to import atlas exported by texture packer and use it frames, take a look here: [UIAtlas](http://www.tasharen.com/?page_id=120).

If you don't want to use whole UI framework for simple process of importing sprites, maybe it would be better to use some package that allows you to just import the sprites from spritesheet and read the data, take a look: [TexturePacker to Sprite](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/217408-TexturePacker-to-Sprite)

Comment: Thanks kreys, but i want to read sprite without NGUI, i want to use texturepacker json to set character idle,run,jump state. have any ideal to question ?